New Wall Old Home - Baseboard Question
I have somewhat a design/DIY question to pose. I live in a Victorian that's gone through a lot - The current master bedroom was originally 2 rooms, in the 70s they knocked down the closets in between for a dance studio. They put up a header that wasn't enough to support the ceiling and made the space ridiculously large for a bedroom so not adding something wasn't an option.
I've put up a wall for in between, it has French doors to the new laundry room/master closet and recessed shelving. But I have really no idea how to transition from the old original baseboards that have been stained to the dark wood to the new wall. I won't be able to match the wood or aesthetic reasonably, but I'm going to need something on the new wall. How do I aesthetically and physically make that transition?

Pictures will help.  Staining new baseboards to match might be possible.  The problem might be finding similar baseboard design if they are the originals.

If you can't match the stain color, your could rip out all the existing baseboards and put in new ones that are stained to match... or just paint all the baseboards so the mismatch is hidden.
